# What is the role of parentheses in this javascript expression?

Tags: javascript

I came across this short snippet ([HERE](https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-code/blob/master/snippets/pick.md))

```js
const pick = (obj, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr in obj && (acc[curr] = obj[curr]), acc), {});
```

And I don't understand the role of parentheses in this part

```js
(curr in obj && (acc[curr] = obj[curr]), acc)
```

```js
() => (... && (... = ...), ...)

// First, parentheses after the arrow function means we are returning what is inside
() => (...)

// This looks like a short if statement
curr in obj && ...

// Why are we grouping the assignment into parentheses here?
(acc[curr] = obj[curr])

// What does (..., ...) is supposed to to 
() => (... && (...), acc)
```

Comment: They do what they've always done: Rearrange operator order. The outer parenthesis are to contain the comma and clarify the arrow function body. The inner ones are to contain the equals.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce so you understand all except the (acc[curr] = obj[curr])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
(curr in obj && (acc[curr] = obj[curr]), acc)
```

is another way of writing the following:

```
if (curr in obj) {
   acc[curr] = obj[curr];
}

return acc;
```

Not only the one-liner is less readable, it can also be considered as abusing the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Code readability is more important than writing *less* lines of code.

> // What does (..., ...) is supposed to do
>
> ```
> () => (... && (...), acc)
> ```

Parenthesis in the following expression:

```
(curr in obj && (acc[curr] = obj[curr]), acc)
```

ensure that:

1. Overall expression is evaluated as a single expression that consists of multiple sub-expressions
2. Assignment is evaluated without the `curr in obj &&` part because without those parenthesis, `curr in obj && acc[curr] = obj[curr]` is invalid syntax.

   With parenthesis, the expression:

   ```
   (acc[curr] = obj[curr])
   ```

   will evaluate to the value of `obj[curr]`. So the expression:

   ```
   curr in obj && (acc[curr] = obj[curr])
   ```

   will become:

   ```
   curr in obj && <assignment value>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses are required because otherwise, this expression:

```
curr in obj && acc[curr] = obj[curr]
```

would be invalid syntax, because the left-hand side of the `=` would evaluate to `curr in obj && acc[curr]` (an expression), not a *reference* that can be assigned to.

But this is horrible code - it's quite confusing. A much better version would be

```
const pick = (obj, arr) => {
    const output = {};
    for (const curr of arr) {
        if (curr in obj) {
            output[curr] = obj[curr]
        }
    }
    return output;
};
```

That's so much easier to understand at a glance, isn't it?

Another option is to filter the entries of the object:

```
const pick = (obj, arr) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => arr.includes(key))
);
```